# XPATH select parent node by type containing text

Tags: xpath

I need to select all n nodes by containing the text "text to match"

```
<n>
  <n>
    <s>text to match</s>
  </n>
  <n>
    <s>ignore</s>
  </n>
  <n>
    <s>text to match</s>
  </n>
  <n>
    text to match
  </n>
</n>
```

I tried `*[contains(string(), "text to match")]` but that selects the outer-most n as well
I would like to get only the *nearest* possibly n.
Any hints?
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to fetch required `n` nodes:

```
//n[normalize-space()='text to match']
```

or

```
//n[contains(., 'text to match') and not(descendant::n)]
```

Comment: Thank you, JaSon, the second example works perfectly! A quick follow up: the real world markup is a libreoffice text xml, the nodes are <text:p>. Unfortunaltely the colon in text:p seems to mess up the query, any hints?

Comment: @Marcel to handle nodes like `text:p` try instead of `//text:p` use `//*[name()='p']`

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I ise that with descendant?

Comment: @Marcel `not(descendant::*[name()='p'])` or do you mean `//*[name()='p' and contains(., 'text to match') and not(descendant::*[name()='p'])]`?

Comment: The second notation is perfect for my needs, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Since `text to match` can appear in nodes with different tag name and you are looking for the nearest parent `n` node, I think

```
//*[contains(text(), "text to match")]/parent::n
```

would make what you are looking for here

Comment: This seems to traverse up to the upper <n> which i was trying to avoid.

Comment: Just asking: have you tried this and this is what you received?